# What word means "inspire towards action"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've seen *inspire* mean two things,

1. To be inspired to go out and make a difference
2. To be inspired, and feel good about something.

Is there a better word to refer to the first definition? I want to say I was *inspired to act*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe the word *[motivated](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/motivate)*, as in *I was motivated by that speech to act in a particular fashion*.

Answer (score 4):

I would highly suggest [*galvanize*](http://www.yourdictionary.com/galvanize).

> v. to inspire or stimulate someone to act. - Yourdictionary.com

Example:

> Although he was now middle-aged, Amundsen, like many others, was galvanized to take a stand in response to actions he considered dishonourable. - *The Last Viking*: The Life of Roald Amundsen

Comment: What a great answer. I've edited to 1) fit our answering 'recommendations'. If you don't approve of the edit, please feel free to roll back. :)

Comment: Galvanized is not correct because it is usually used for groups of people.

Comment: @michael_timofeev, it is often used for groups, but not anywhere near always.  You can use it for individuals, as in the cited example, with no confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You were *motivated*.

Google dictionary, sense 2:

> motivated (past participle, past tense of mo·ti·vate) Verb:
>   1. Provide (someone) with a motive for doing something.
>   2. Stimulate (someone's) interest in or enthusiasm for doing something.

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest *stirred*, as in *I was stirred to action.*

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stir) defines *To stir* as: *to rouse to activity : evoke strong feelings in*

According to [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stir) it can mean: **(1)** *arouse strong feeling in (someone); move or excite*; and **(2)** *arouse or prompt (a feeling or memory) or inspire (the imagination)*.

Note that it is still necessary to explicitly say what you were stirred *into doing something*. I don't know of any one word that conveys both the inspiration as well as the consequent action.